# Proper way to unsubscribe event handlers to make the subscriber eligible for GC?

Tags: .net, silverlight, memory-leaks, event-handling, garbage-collection

I have an publisher and subscriber. the subscriber subscribes itself from the publisher.
I need to make sure that when the subscriber goes out of scope, it should unsubscribe from that event, to be eligible for `GC`.

Here's a basic scenario:

```
class Service
{
  public event Action PrintMessage;
  public void RaisePrintMessage()
  {
    if (PrintMessage != null) PrintMessage();
  }
}

class Session
{
  public Session(Service service)
  {
    _service = service;
    _service.PrintMessage += _service_PrintMessage;
  }

  void _service_PrintMessage()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
  }

  private readonly Service _service;
  public Service Service
  {
    get
    {
      return _service;
    }
  }

  ~Session()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Session finalized.");
  }
}

class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    var service = new Service();
    CreateSession(service);
    service.RaisePrintMessage();

    Console.ReadKey();
  }

  private static void CreateSession(Service service)
  {
    var session = new Session(service);
  }
}
```

The output as you can expect is `Hello world` (and not `Session finalized.`) since once the Subscriber subscribed during `Create Session`, `Service` has now got a reference to that `Session` and is not GCed.

In my case, I cannot change the `CreateSession` method nor don't I have control of the constructing / destructing of the subscriber, I do want to make sure I implement `Session` so that once it goes out of scope it should unsubscribe from `Service`.

(My particular case is I'm using Silverlight with Prism and MVVM, Prism controls the life time of the ViewModel which is the subscriber, but I don't think that matters, I want to make my VM aware that Prism doesn't need it anymore)

Is there a way I can make the subscriber aware of going out of scope giving it the chance to unsubscribe and GCed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good way to do it:

[LeakEvent -> WeakEvent](http://bit.ly/leakevent-weakevent)